# R Programming: Running multiple scripts from 1 R file on the command line

Tags: r, command-line

I have a script called ProcessMeta.R that contains multiple functions that creates meta data and organizes a large amount of folders.  I run this nearly everyday and I would like to automate this.

So I go to the working directory my data lives in and use "Rscript ProcessMeta.R" at the command line.  **It doesn't run any of the sub functions**.  Are there any flags I need to set so the sub functions are run as well?

Rscript will work on a helloWorld.R test so I know my path variables are set up right.  Any ideas?

```
ProcessMeta <- function () {
require(XML)
require(uuid)
require(data.table)
require(sqldf)
require(zoo)

#---------------
# Initilize tables and global variables
initializeTables()  
homeWD <<-getwd()
#---------------

filedir <- findfiles()
tmp <- sapply(filedir,createMeta)
adjData<- fixData(DirsPath)

validateData(adjData)

createXML(adjData)

moveToProcessed(adjData)
addToSQL()
}
```

Comment: The script file only appears to define the `ProcessMeta` function. It never actually calls the function. Maybe just add `ProcessMeta()` to the end of the file? Or remove the function definition completely?

Comment: Try rerunning it with `Rscript --verbose ProcessMeta.R` to get an idea of what's going wrong. It's possible that the environment used by `Rscript` is not the same as what you use in an interactive session, in which case it might not be able to access packages / functions you are calling. You could do something like `Rscript -e 'cat(c(.libPaths(), installed.packages()[,1]), sep="\n")'` and compare the results to what you get when running that in an interactive session.

Comment: @nrussell, I think this is my problem.  I ran the --verbose and got this: "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3\bin\x64\Rterm.exe --slave --no-restore"

Comment: @MrFlick, that worked thanks!.  I'm used to RStudio so that wasn't in there.